# Formal proof that IR_L IC_H are binding constraints

Tags: microeconomics, proof

Two types of customers, equal proportions:

$q_H(p_H)=20-0.5p_H$,
$q_L(p_L)=20-p_L$

The firm cant differentiate between them.
It wishes to create a menu of two possible taarifs, $(p_H,T_H),(p_L,T_L)$

$T_i$ a fixed cost on customer $i$ and $p_i$ is the price per good $q$.

1. Consumer surplus is $CS_H=q_H^2$,$CS_L=q_L^2/2$
2. The target function

$$
\max{\pi} = p_H(q_H)q_H+p_L(q_L)q_L+T_H+T_L-4q_H-4q_L
$$
$$
=36q_H-2q_H^2+16q_L-q_L^2+T_H+T_L
$$
$$st.$$
$$
IR_H: CS_H(p_H)-T_H\geq0
$$
$$
IR_L:CS_L(p_L)-T_L\geq0
$$
$$
IC_H:CS_H(p_H)-T_H\geq CS_H(p_L)-T_L
$$
$$
IC_L: CS_L(p_L)-T_L \geq CS_2(p_H)-T_H
$$
Now, I know that $IR_L$ and $IC_H$ are binding constraints because there is no distortion at the top and the low demand consumer will have a 0 net surplus, but cant seem the formalize a mathematical proof for it.

I've tried first supposing $IR_L$ is not binding, thus you could raise $T_L$ and consumer L will still purchase, but got stuck showing it won't hinder $IC_L$. Proving $IC_H$ is binding seems to be more difficult.

I would greatly appreciate your assistance! thank you.

BTW

it's not homework, but a marathon for a final exam in four days :)

Answer (score 1):

If $IR_L$ is not binding, you can increase both $T_L$ *and $T_H$* by the same amount: Such increases do not violate either of the following:

1. $IR_L$ is not violated as it's initially not binding;
2. Neither $IC_H$ nor $IC_L$ is affected because both sides increase by the same amount; and
3. $IR_H$ is not affected because it's implied by $IR_L$ and $IC_H$ (and the fact that $CS_H(p)>CS_L(p)$ for all $p$).

Comment: Thanks! what about showing that $IC_H$ is binding which seems to be the more difficult proof?

Comment: @JohnPine: If $IC_H$ doesn't bind, then increase $T_H$, which makes $IC_L$ easier to satisfy and doesn't affect $IR_H$ because of point 3 above.